# EJB3 : orm.xml : is it possible to have multiple orm.xml files?

Tags: jakarta-ee, orm, ejb-3.0

I work on a big EJB3 project and my orm.xml is very big too.
Is it possible to include others orm files in an orm "parent" ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no include syntax for orm.xml, but you can specify multiple `<mapping-file>` in persistence.xml.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in META-INF add orm1.xml, orm2.xml.

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="UnitPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>co.com.prueba.modelo.Person</class>    
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
    </properties>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm1.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm2.xml</mapping-file>
  </persistence-unit>
```